# Should I use a service/broadcastreceiver in order to constantly scan wifi?

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, wifi

So I just want to make sure that the architecture I am using is correct here (which I am sure it is not as I am new). Now my application wants to be a background running application, and it starts and stops a service according to the user, who will be pressing the on/off toggle switch in the app's main page/activity.

So they press "on" and the service begins.

What my service does so far is, through a handler, repeatedly do a scan of the wifi in the background.

So something like:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

wifi.startScan();
```

Is run repeatedly every...20 seconds.

There is also a broadcastreceiver registered to receive the SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION and processes information of the wifi there. Then proceeds to spit out messages to the screen using Toast (Toast being this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

What I want to know is if I'm on the right track here, and whether it is at all possible to somehow send information between the receiver/service? (for example I would like to save the values of some variables between each scan, so I would like to send them back to the service from the receiver)

I can post code here if you guys think it is needed. :)

Comment: **"repeatedly do a scan of the wifi"** Can you clarify what you mean by "scan"? Are you simply testing to see if wifi is available or searching for available access points (SSIDs) or searching for devices connected to the wifi network?

Comment: The scan is a method from WifiManager class, and it basically requests a scan for the access points. Then when the scan is done, the broadcast receiver captures the event, and then proceeds to process the data from the scan (eg. check their signal strenght/SSID's/LinkSpeed.) Hopefully that makes sense